# Tool to detect (and delete) empty images?

Tags: image-processing, batch

I've exported a tile layer from qGis using [QMetaTiles plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QMetaTiles/).

It outputs a folder that contains a lot of images (the tiles).
But most of those images are blank (full transparency, no visual data); and there is no option in the plugin for not rendering those.

So i'm looking for a tool that would be able to detect (and delete) images if they are empty; so I don't have to upload them.

Does anyone knows a good (simple) tool ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if the empty tiles can't be identified easier e.g. by their hash as they should be all the same (same content and typically for minimizing file size map files should not contain meta data). Alternatively sort the files by size in an Explorer like tool that shows the exact file size in bytes. BTW what is your definition of empty? An PNG image only showing a fully transparent image?

Comment: Please clarify if by "empty" you mean a 0 byte file or whether "empty" means an image file that has no image just a uniform pixel field (uniform color).

Comment: @tckosvic I edited the question.